# Ubuntu 14.04 does not boot after installing

Tags: boot

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 after my Windows 8.1 was not boot at all. After the installation I removed the USB drive and restarted the computer, but It had "Checking media presence -Media Present -Start PXE Over ipv4 then after a while, it says "ERROR: No boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed" Now I have no idea what to do and I fear thier is no fixing it. I have also tried reinstalling the OS and it would not work. I have done the a "Check disk for defects option" and it has found errors on 2 files. NOTE: i have a 64-bit coputer with the 64-bit version installed. Thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but I have got it fixed, I just needed to use Boot Repair